# iDRAC 8 systemPowerState returning 0 over SNMP

Tags: snmp, drac

We're upgrading our aging fleet of Dell servers to new 13th Gen Dells with iDRAC 8 enterprises.

We are polling the power status of the server via SNMP with the following OID:

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.674.10892.5.2.4.0 (systemPowerState)
```

This is meant to return the value of `4 (on)`, and often it does. But it also often returns a state of `0`, which causes false alerts to trigger.

Has anyone else seen this on iDRAC 8? I'm going to open a case with Dell to see if there's a known issue (it, uh, wouldn't be the first time we've found a bug in Dell firmware) but I wanted see if anyone else has seen this first, and if you had a workaround.

---

After a few weeks of looking at this, I don't have a solution yet, but now we're also getting the occasional "unknown" data from the voltage sensors, saying that the 1.5v rail is going offline. It's not happening just to a single server either. We now have multiple R630's returning this data over SNMP and raising what we assume are false alerts.

I have done some tech support with Dell, but do not have a resolution.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same "Power Status" issue with 4x R730. Updating the firmware to the latest available version (2.15.10.10_A00) did not solve it.

The SNMP values returned for DellPowerState should be one of:

1 ⇒ Other
2 ⇒ Unknown
3 ⇒ Off
4 ⇒ On

0 is not documented. The work around we use is to consider "0" like "4", so we don't get an alert when the idrac randomly returns "0".

I guess we'll have to wait for a future version of the idrac firmware from Dell to fix it.